# HTML: How to add click function separately to div if has same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here I want to add 4 div's inside a timeline div

This looks something like this

```
<div id="timeline" >
     <div class="timeline-bar t-1"></div>
     <div class="timeline-bar t-2"></div>
     <div class="timeline-bar t-3"></div>
     <div class="timeline-bar t-4"></div>
</div>
```

Now I want to implemented something like this, when I click on div2 it would alert me, how to pick this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".timeline-bar").click(function() {
        alert('Item selected is DIV no 2'); //this line
      });
    });
```

Now I want to click and alert like this "Your clicked DIV2"
what happening right now is on-click is working but not separately and all at once.

How to make every one seperate clickable for a child div with single function

Comment: *on-click is working but not separately and all at once.* This sentence isn't clear to me, can you clarify? Do you mean that you get an alert for every element when a single one is clicked (sounds weird), or what?

Comment: What is `obj` exactly? To me seems like `obj` is rather an Array...

Comment: Yes its an array

Comment: @CertainPerformance I want to make separate click event for each div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var k='';
for(i = 0;i < 4; i++){
    k +='<div class="timeline-bar t-'+i+'">in '+i+'</div>';
   }
   
document.getElementById('timeline').innerHTML = k;

$("#timeline" ).on( "click", "div.timeline-bar", function() {
   console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="timeline" ></div>
```

Comment: may I ask where `obj` disappeared?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan he was already in another dimension before I could even write this snippet

Answer (score 1):

```js
// obj is actully an array, so let's call it "bars" for sanity
const bars = ["One, Click us!", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"];

// Define the "bar" Element Component
const $newBar = (text, i) => $('<div/>', { // PS... remember that index i is 0 based.
  text,
  class: `timeline-bar`,
  on: {
    click() {
      alert(`Item selected is DIV No ${i+1}`);
    }
  }
});

// Create all components from array
// And append them all at once
$('#timeline').append(bars.map($newBar));
```

```html
<div id="timeline"></div>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```js
$('.timeline').on('click', function() {
  alert($(this).index());
});
```

```css
.timeline {
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline"></div>
<div class="timeline"></div>
<div class="timeline"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: 1. First of, there's no such `.timeline` in OP's question. 2. This is just waiting for someone to change the HTML markup to fail. 3. (related to 2.) I'd rather cache the elements like `const $timelineElements` and than do: `$timelineElements.index(this)` (4. why an external link when Stack Overflow has Runnable Snippets?)

Comment: Hello, well it’s not always punctuality that counts but rather give some help. The OP seems to have gotten what they wanted. Also the runnable snippets could use some improvement...

Comment: You're welcome to suggest ideas and improvements on [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/). Meanwhile I added a snippet and removed the unnecessary external link. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan - No, don't mind at all! Thanks!